# Custom Data Reader (LMDB) in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In general, there are three ways I can think of for reading custom data in TF:

1. **Native Implementation / Custom Data Reader**
   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/new_data_formats/index.html
2. **Python Function Wrapping**
   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html
3. **Placeholders**
   I have already implemented this succesfully. But I want an in-graph solution like (1) or (2).

Can someone elaborate on the pros and cons (mainly from performance/efficiency standpoint) the difference between (1) and (2), so I can use the queue runners.

My feeling says (1) should be the most efficient and robust way. But that solution would not be portable unless I share or PR the code and other users would have to compile. Whereas (2) and (3) are portable, right?

I have also opened a feature request '[LMDB Reading Feature](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4392)' issue on GitHub that was misinterpreted and closed as a question.

**UPDATE**

TensorFlow not has a native reader: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(2)** and **(3)** Both suffer from Python's GIL; eventually you'll probably lock up. This implemented is therefore also slower because it's not in-graph, and will be quite hard to parallelize correctly. It's quick and easy but also suboptimal. So, go for 1 to go pro;

I have also found that (1) has two solutions:

**(1A) Implement a custom op in the source.**

This is the way if you want your Op to end up in the Tensorflow source-code at some point, quality permitting.

**(1B) Implement a stand-alone custom op.**

This turns out to be very easy and portable. You can just compile your own .cc code, and register it through Python. No rebuilding of source code required: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op